# Http 403 - CORS error using RSS parser in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rss

I am getting the following error when I download a RSS feed from another domain:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Status code 403

 37 | componentDidMount() {
  38 |     (async () => {
  39 | 
> 40 |         const feed = await parser.parseURL(CORS_PROXY + 'https://www.reddit.com/.rss');
     | ^  41 |         console.log(feed.title); // feed will have a `foo` property, type as a string
  42 | 
  43 |         // feed.items.forEach(item => {
```

According to the [RSS parser doc](https://github.com/rbren/rss-parser) it says that if I use a proxy I can by pass CORS security but it's still blocking it, it seems. I am using firefox(latest). Any ideas?

Comment: Wrap it in a try/catch and log the error? What's the error being thrown?

Answer (score 1):

The URL that you want to parse, https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.reddit.com/.rss, returns 403 with error

> This demo of CORS Anywhere should only be used for development purposes, see https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/301.